# create table with auto increment as first col and data type as second

Tags: sql, increment

maybe I am over thinking this these are the instructions

create four new tables: my_interests, my_professions, my_seeking and my_status. These tables should contain two columns: one for an id and another for the data value. Populate these from the appropriate columns in the my_contacts table. Once your new tables are ready, you can replace the original data columns with id numbers matching the applicable id values in your new my_professions and my_status tables.

SO THE WAY I READ THE FIRST IS I HAVE THE FIRST COL AS AN AUTO INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, THE NEXT VALUE WOULD BE THE DATA TYPE, I AM STARTING WITH MY_STATUS FIRST AND THE TYPES WOULD BE

COMMITED_RELATIONSHIP

DIVORCED

MARRIED

SINGLE

WIDOWED

AND MY AUTO_INC NUMBER WOULD CORRESPOND TO THE ID OF DATA, IN OTHER WORDS

01**COMMITED

02**DIVORCED

03** AND SO ON

AM I CORRECT IN THE WAY I AM READING THE INSTRUCTIONS? 
AND IF SO NOT QUITE SURE HOW TO DO THIS, I KNOW HOW TO CREATE THE TABLE, AND I UNDERSTAND INSERT INTO AND VALUES, BUT HOW DO I INSERT THE VALUES AND AUTO INCREMENT? I REALLY DISLIKE PROGRAMMING :(

thanks in advance

Comment: MySQL 5.2.38             CREATE TABLE my_status
(
  id                        INT            PRIMARY KEY   AUTO_INCREMENT,
  status_type               VARCHAR(50)
  )
    ;

Comment: I understand what I just posted just not how to populate the table to correspond to the data, thanks again

Comment: oh thank you thank you, that works perfectly, I think I can do the other 3 tables from that one, I may get some sleep tonight after all!

Comment: ok that worked great, now on to the second part which was Once your new tables are ready, you can replace the original data columns with id numbers matching the applicable id values in your new my_professions and my_status tables.

NOW IF I AM NOT MISTAKEN I WOULD USE A ALTER_TABLE COMMAND TO ADJUST THE VALUES IN THE ORIG TABLE TO CORRISPOND TO THE NEW PK AUTO INCREMENT VALUES THAT I JUST ASSIGNED THEM? OR WOULD THE UPDATE COMMAND WORK BETTER? I THINK THAT IS WHAT I WILL TRY FIRST

Comment: Ok **" you can replace the original data columns with id numbers matching the applicable id values in your new my_professions and my_status tables."** what do you exactly mean by this? its to vague as what you want! Be more specific about the problem.

Comment: UPDATE my_contacts 
SET status = replace(status, 'single', '4') 
WHERE status LIKE 'sing%';                    ok this works fine, but how can I replace more than one status at the same time? I am thinking with either the AND or OR, but not sure...thanks

Comment: yes I am using MySQL workbench, I am taking a college course, they gave us the db, and I think the whole class is based on modifying the existing db. I can post the schema if you want,

Comment: if I try and copy and paste it is too big for the comment window, is there another way to post the schema

Comment: i can try to do a command line dump

Comment: i think i have it saved to a .mwb file extension but don't see a way to upload

Comment: Provide a SqlFiddle in sqlfiddle.com,provide schema of my_contacts! Ok Atlease post the code used to create your table!!!!

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c22d19/1

Comment: Ok Now with the fiddle what is the problem?

Comment: i want to create an update statement that allows me to change more than one item at a time, i got this code to work for one of the status items, but would like to write it all in one update*********UPDATE my_contacts 
set status = replace(status, 'single', '4')
WHERE status like 'sing%'

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT AT US! Writing all uppercase is considered rude.

Comment: and the rest would be divorced=2, married=3, single=4, etc. but how do i connect or add multiple SET statements?

Comment: sorry i am not shouting, just trying to insert what is my comments and what is instructions ive been given

Comment: please check the new answer(i tried to understand as to what exactly you want but failed. So answered it assuming this is what you want) and dont forget to accept the answer!!!

Answer (score 0):

`Create table my_status (status_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,status_type varchar(20), PRIMARY KEY (status_id));` To Create

`insert into my_status (status_type) values("Single"),("Divorced"),("Married");` to insert

Answer (score 0):

`Create table my_status (status_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,status_type varchar(20), PRIMARY KEY (status_id));` To Create

`insert into my_status (status_type) values("Single"),("Divorced"),("Married");` to insert

Possible Answer to your 2nd question

```
CREATE TABLE `my_status` (
  `status_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `status_type` varchar(30),PRIMARY KEY(`status_id`) );
CREATE TABLE `my_profession` (
  `profession_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `profession_type` varchar(30),PRIMARY KEY(`profession_id`) );
CREATE TABLE `my_contacts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `last_name` varchar(30) ,
  `first_name` varchar(20) ,
  `email` varchar(50) ,
  `gender` char(1),
  `birthday` date ,
  `profession_id` int(11),
  `location` varchar(50),
  `status_id` int(11),
  `interests` varchar(200),
  `seeking` varchar(200),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (status_id) 
        REFERENCES my_status(status_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (profession_id) 
        REFERENCES my_profession(profession_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


insert into my_status (status_type) values("Single"),("Divorced"),("Married");
insert into my_profession (profession_type) values("Writer"),("CA"),("Developer");

INSERT INTO `my_contacts` (`last_name`,`first_name`,`email`,`gender`,`birthday`,`profession_id`,`location`,`status_id`,`interests`,`seeking`) VALUES ('Anderson','Jillian','jill_anderson@ \nbreakneckpizza.com','F','1980-09-05',1,'Palo Alto, CA',1,'kayaking, reptiles','relationship, friends');
INSERT INTO `my_contacts` (`last_name`,`first_name`,`email`,`gender`,`birthday`,`profession_id`,`location`,`status_id`,`interests`,`seeking`) VALUES ('Kenton','Leo','lkenton@starbuzzcoffee.com','M','1974-01-10',2,'San Francisco, CA',2,'women','women to date');
INSERT INTO `my_contacts` (`last_name`,`first_name`,`email`,`gender`,`birthday`,`profession_id`,`location`,`status_id`,`interests`,`seeking`) VALUES ('McGavin','Darrin',' captainlove@headfirsttheater.com','M','1966-01-23',3,'San Diego, CA',3,'sailing, fishing, yachting','women for casual relationships');
INSERT INTO `my_contacts` (`last_name`,`first_name`,`email`,`gender`,`birthday`,`profession_id`,`location`,`status_id`,`interests`,`seeking`) VALUES ('xyz','abc',' xyz@abc.com','F','1966-01-24',1,'San Diego, CA',3,'sailing, fishing, yachting, golfing','women for casual relationships');


select * from my_contacts;
select * from my_status;
select * from my_profession;
SELECT * FROM my_contacts WHERE status_id IN 
  (SELECT status_id FROM my_status WHERE status_type = 'Married');
```

Hope this is what you want!!!

Comment: wow thanks that was a lot of work, really all I want to do is update multiple rows in one column. from what I have found on the web it would look something like this********UPDATE my_contacts
     SET status = CASE id
         WHEN status = 'committed relationship' THEN '1'
         WHEN status = 'divorced'               THEN '2'
         WHEN status = 'married'                THEN '3'
         WHEN status = 'single'                 THEN '4'
         WHEN status = 'widowed'                THEN '5'
     END*************don't know if its right, worked but now status col is returning null values

Comment: this works but I would have to do this code for every row and I have 4 tables and 54 rows, I would like to do ea table by its self. as once I change the data from its orig txt value to the corresponding number value, these values will become my fk's in my join tables. Hopefully I am explaining this better (got some sleep) and being new I don't know all the terminology just yet

Comment: UPDATE my_contacts 
set status = replace(status, 'widowed', '5')
WHERE status like 'wid%'

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE my_contacts
 SET status='1'
 WHERE status='committed relationship';
    UPDATE my_contacts
    set status= '2'
    where status='divorced';
        UPDATE my_contacts
        set status= '3'
        where status='married';
            UPDATE my_contacts
            set status= '4'
            where status='single';
                UPDATE my_contacts
                set status= '5'
                where status='widowed';
```

**THANKS EVERYONE!! (yeah that time I shouted, lol!)**

Comment: now I am open to a better way of doing this, as I am sure there is one. just trying to get the project done, so please feel free to point me in the right direction!